# What's difference between printing code in and out of curly braces?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, curly-braces

What's difference between returning out of curly-braces and in of it within for loops?

I have this code making 'factorial' in for loops code quiz of Udacity and it is marked as 'right answer' only if 'console.log(solution) is out of for loop braces. Why can I put it inside for loop? Can't really understand why is that.

```
var solution = 12;
for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
solution = solution * i; 
  console.log(solution); /* Why inside of the loop like this is 
wrong? */
}


var solution = 12;
for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
solution = solution * i; // 12 = 1 * 2 * 3 * .... 12

}
console.log(solution); /* only it works when it's out of the loop 
like this one but why???? */
```

Comment: You are using C++? What si wrong?

Comment: nah, it's javascript. On Udacity website, it marks me as wrong answer when it was inside in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that inside the loop you are outputting the contents, or the current state of `solution` *every time the loop repeats* (in this case 11 times), when it's outside the loop body, you are only outputting the *final* state of the variable, or just 1 time.

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand?  It really can't get much simpler

Comment: Without knowing how the Udacity system is scoring, in the simplest answer I can give is that the first bit of code outputs 11 _different_ answers, whereas the second bit of code only gives one.  Run both versions of the code and compare the output, it's really quite obvious.

Comment: Have solved the problem. so when It's inside it prints every repeated step, and it's outside, console only shows the all total number. Thanks for your help!